# MYSQL one-to-many relationship pushing into array

Tags: php, mysql, json, left-join

I am making query to DB

```
    $query="SELECT com.id, com.name, ctx.LastName, ctx.FirstName, com.company_phone,addr.City, addr.Street ";
    $query.="FROM Connections as con ";
    $query.="LEFT JOIN Companies as com on con.company_id = com.id ";
    $query.="LEFT JOIN Contacts as ctx on con.contact_id = ctx.id ";
    $query.="LEFT JOIN addresses as addr on addr.id = com.Legal_address ";
    if($value['db']=='companies') $query.="WHERE LOWER(com.".$value['model'].") RLIKE LOWER('".$value['val']."')";
    else if($value['db']=='contacts') $query.="WHERE LOWER(ctx.FirstName) RLIKE LOWER('".$value['val']."') OR LOWER(ctx.LastName) RLIKE LOWER('".$value['val']."')";
    else if($value['db']=='addresses') $query.="WHERE LOWER(addr.City) RLIKE LOWER('".$value['val']."') OR LOWER(addr.Street) RLIKE LOWER('".$value['val']."')";
```

and then sending the result back to client. As a result I can see, for example:

```
[
 {
  id:1,
  name: google,
  contact: Smith,
  ....
 },
 {
  id:1,
  name: google,
  contact: Black,
  ....
 },
 {
  id:2,
  name: microsoft,
  contact: Walker,
  ....
 }
 ....
```

But I want to see no duplicated rows, but arrays where there is One-to-many relationships. Like second example:

```
[
 {
  id:1,
  name: google,
  contact: [Smith, Black],
  ....
 },

 {
  id:2,
  name: microsoft,
  contact: Walker,
  ....
 }
 ....
```

My knowledge of SQL is very bad. I have already been told that `WHERE`+`JOIN` as bad mood. So is it possible to change my query so that it will be like in the second example.

P.S. Both arrays I write with structure of json format as I sending response back to client.

Comment: this link may help you - [MySQL Group_Concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: in your query you need to add `group by com.id` at the end and in select part you need to add `group_concat(ctx.LastName)` (Assuming contact is your lastname column)

Comment: I have put this in answer, you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44698338/2679536)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query="SELECT com.id, com.name, CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT(ctx.LastName),']') AS contact, ctx.LastName, ctx.FirstName, com.company_phone,addr.City, addr.Street ";
$query.="FROM Connections as con ";
$query.="LEFT JOIN Companies as com on con.company_id = com.id ";
$query.="LEFT JOIN Contacts as ctx on con.contact_id = ctx.id ";
$query.="LEFT JOIN addresses as addr on addr.id = com.Legal_address ";
if($value['db']=='companies') $query.="WHERE LOWER(com.".$value['model'].") RLIKE LOWER('".$value['val']."')";
else if($value['db']=='contacts') $query.="WHERE LOWER(ctx.FirstName) RLIKE LOWER('".$value['val']."') OR LOWER(ctx.LastName) RLIKE LOWER('".$value['val']."')";
else if($value['db']=='addresses') $query.="WHERE LOWER(addr.City) RLIKE LOWER('".$value['val']."') OR LOWER(addr.Street) RLIKE LOWER('".$value['val']."')";
$query .= " GROUP BY com.id ";
```

I assumed `LastName` column as `Contact` from your output JSON.

Comment: But group_concat make something like {  contact: "Smith,White"   } instead of { contact: [Smith, White]  }

Comment: @RoGGeR, I have updated my query by using `CONCAT`. Hope you will get expected result.

Comment: This is strange, but looks like it still a string {CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT(ctx.LastName),']') : "[xxx,kjhgfd]" }

Comment: it will consider as a string until you manually not define it as an array before json_encode. For that, you have to manipulate your result object/array.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably going to have to take the data and make the array that you want.

```
    $data = array();
    foreach ($result as $fields) {
        $key = $fiels['name']; // or $item['info_id']
        if (!isset($data[$key])) {
            $data[$key] = array();
        }

        $data[$key][] = $field;
    }

// Build your table with the new $data array
```

This is just an example. As it points out, if your name field isn't unique, you will need to build your array on a unique key. Not terribly different from this, as you could probably just change instances of `$field['name']` to `$field['info_id']`.